# The file provided is not a valid service package. Detailed error code: InvalidOperationException in azure

Tags: azure

We have to update web.config entry of Azure package file which got deployed into production environment. We dowloaded cspkg file and unzipped the content and modified our web.config and did compressed back to zip and changed extension to cspkg . When we upload package , we r recieving error below
"The file provided is not a valid service package. Detailed error code: InvalidOperationException in azure"

Any one is having idea on this matter?

Answer (score 1):

'Tampering' with the cspkg file is not supported . Try re-creating a new cspkg file using [CSPack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg432988.aspx).

Comment: Hi Sandrino, I unzip the content, brought my approot folder and ran cspack command pointing to dll in approot, CSPkg is generated but cspkg is 30% lesser in size when i compare with cspkg which get generated thru visual studio.

Comment: I compared the original CSPkg to the new CSPkg and noticed that mine does not have a `sitesroot/0` - it was duplicating the site content that was in `approot` in the original. The new CSPkg only contained the `approot`. This has something to do with how VS.NET creates the package (physical dir) versus using the CSPACK tool directly. This explains the size reduction.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue my self, followed the instruction in msdn. I unzipped it and did packaging using cspack tool

Answer (score 1):

Use cspack.exe to regenerate the package. Use the below command.

```
cspack.exe "path_to_csdef_File\ServiceDefinition.csdef" /role:<RoleName>;<path_to_Binaries\approot> /out:D:\NewPackage.cspkg /rolePropertiesFile:<rolename>;<path_to_entry_point_file\entrypoint.txt>
```

Detailed steps to regenerate package are mentioned in this post.

https://web.archive.org/web/20160910170824/https://amoghnatu.net/2016/09/08/recreate-azure-cloud-service-package/